# Select element based on input value length with CSS

Tags: css

I have an input field

```
<input readonly="readonly" step="1" value="0" type="number">
```

Users will click on a numberpad on the screen and the value of the number field will change accordingly.

I want is to change font size based on value size (single-digit, double-digit, triple-digit).

I know you can select things like

```
[att=str] :- attribute value is exactly matching to str

[att*=str] :-  attribute value contains str – value can contain str anywhere either in middle or at end.

[att^=str] :- attribute value starting with str

[att$=str] :- attribute value ends with str
```

These are nice but `str` must be exact for it to match. Is there a way to select an element with CSS with a regex? Something like:

```
// select input with single-digit value
input[value=\d] { ... }

// select input with double-digit value
input[value=\d\d] { ... }

// select input with triple-digit value
input[value=\d\d\d] { ... }
```

If not, I'll just use classes and JavaScript

Comment: Just a note on the user experience side of things, a user won't know what the default font size is and inputting a number won't mean much. It's a better experience to have a font resizer where the user can press a button to increase/decrease the font. You can set max/min size. Or just have 3 sizes for example and the user can click on a button to change the size to 1 of the 3.

Comment: Can you use JavaScript?

Comment: @Scath yes but I was wondering if there was a CSS solution

Comment: CSS can't style based on *content*...it can only style based on elements and their position in relation to other elements.

Comment: The attribute selector only works for the elements initial attribute value. It isn't re-evaluated when the value changes.

Comment: No good answers so I used classes and JS instead. https://media.giphy.com/media/NsB2dRp8nWVlp3cyoI/giphy.gif

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use pure CSS to check the length and change the font accordingly, you mentioned you could use JavaScript if this was the case. You can check the length or the inputs value on the `onchange` event and set the font size accordingly.

```js
document.getElementById('txt').value = 0

function checkLen(x) {
  if (x.value.length >= 3) {
    x.style.fontSize = '20px'
  } else if (x.value.length >= 2) {
    x.style.fontSize = '14px'
  }
}

function plusOne() {
  var box = document.getElementById('txt')
  box.value++
    checkLen(box)
}
```

```html
<input id="txt" onchange="checkLen(this); return false;" readonly="readonly" step="1" type="number"> <input onclick="plusOne(); return false;" type="button">
```